# python split numeric in string

Tags: python, regex, string, module, split

I was wondering what is the easiest way(probably regex) to separate numbers in a string in a below way.
Example: `"abc12de34f5"`
to: `["abc", "12", "de", "34", "f", "5"]`

however if there is conjuction mark in the string seperate this way:
Example: `"abc1,2de3.4f5"`
to: `["abc", "1,2", "de", "3.4", "f", "5"]`

Thanks for any suggestions and comments

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "abc12de34f5"
>>> re.findall(r'[\d\W]+|[a-zA-Z]+', s)
['abc', '12', 'de', '34', 'f', '5']
>>> t = "abc1,2de3.4f5"
>>> re.findall(r'[\d\W]+|[a-zA-Z]+', t)
['abc', '1,2', 'de', '3.4', 'f', '5']
```

Comment: @eumiro: Good call. fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Joel Cornett, works fine, however I need to do this on the unicode text(cyrilic), how can I use that regula expression in this case?
I guess u[a-яА-Я] won't work. Thanks

Comment: @BoldO: You can modify `[a-z]` for any range of characters, although you might have to do several ranges (i.e. `[a-zA-ZÀ-ῼ]`) to match the characters you want. Also, make sure to specify the `re.UNICODE` flag on `re.findall()` in order to get `\d` and `\W` to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

A non -regex solution using itertools.groupby

```
>>> st = "abc1,2de3.4f5"
>>> [''.join(v) for _, v in groupby(st,key = str.isalpha)]
['abc', '1,2', 'de', '3.4', 'f', '5']
>>> st = "abc12de34f5"
>>> [''.join(v) for _, v in groupby(st,key = str.isalpha)]
['abc', '12', 'de', '34', 'f', '5']
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhijit, works fine, however I need to do this on the unicode text(cyrilic), any ideas how ? Thanks

Comment: @BoldO: Try `unicode.isalpha` instead of `str.isalpha` (If using Py2.X)